# Finding x from Inverse Circular Function equation

Tags: inverse-function

Find $x$ when $\sin^{-1}(x)+\sin^{-1}(1-x)=\cos^{-1}(x)$

I guess it's based on some trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://m.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/find-the-value-of-x-sin-1x-sin-1-1-x-cos-1x/inverse-trigonometric-functions/7265893

refer to the first answer in this link